# How to find row number of cell containing special character along with alphanumeric characters?

Tags: excel, vba

I have written code to get row number from the range("C:C") wherein I find matching value/text as that in cells(3,3).

This code works as long as cells(3,3) has either pure number or pure text. But as soon as cells(3,3) has special character e.g.*~* *(as in MBGH3345~123)* the code returns error.

> run time error 400

```
Public Sub Find_Row_Number()

Dim wb As Workbook  
Dim ws As Worksheet  
Dim FindCell As Range  
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook  
Set ws = ActiveSheet  

Set FindCell = ws.Range("C:C").Find(cells(3,3))
'value to be searched is in cells(3,3)

If Not FindCell Is Nothing Then
    Msgbox (FindCell.Row)
Else
    Msgbox ("Error")
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Won't your code just always find C3 ?

Comment: I would want to edit the line of code as >>>                                                         '''Set FindCell = ws.Range("C:C").Find(cells(i,12)) ''' before this I would set i as integer, i=3 & with do loop value of i changes using i=i+1

Comment: Thank you Tim Williams. I will try your suggestion & get back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how this gives you a run-time error but:

The tilde `~` is used to escape wildcard characters such as `?` and `*`, so if you want to match an *actual* tilde then you need to escape the tilde in the search value with ... another tilde.

So `MBGH3345~~123` in C3 would match `MBGH3345~123` for example.

If your search term might contain tilde characters (and they're not intended as wildcard escapes) then you could do this:

```
Set FindCell = ws.Range("B:B").Find(Replace(Cells(3, 3).Value, "~", "~~"), _
                                    LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
```

**Edit** - here's how I'd do what you seem to want to do:  `Match` is faster than `Find` here  -

```
Sub CheckData()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, c As Range, v, m

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    For Each c In ws.Range(ws.Range("L3"), ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp)).Cells

        v = c.Value
        If Len(v) > 0 Then

            v = Replace(v, "~", "~~") 'escape any tilde

            m = Application.Match(v, ws.Range("C:C"), 0)
            If IsError(m) Then
                c.Offset(0, -1).Value = "New"
                'add this to the master list...
                ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = c.Value
            Else
                c.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Line " & m
            End If
        End If

    Next c

End Sub
```